# Effect of viscosity in a rolling body and it's contrast to non-viscous fluids

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

while working on problems related to fluid mechanics i came across a problem in which we were asked to find the kinetic energy of a sphere which is under pure rolling and has non viscous fluid filled inside it. here you can see the figure :[image]

so my initial thoughts were to write the moment of inertia of the whole body about center of mass and then proceed as normal. But to my surprise this was not correct so i thought more about this and made a conclusion that if the fluid is non viscous then maybe we don't have to consider its rolling motion. This assumption made me do this question but i am not sure whether it's correct or not. I want to know what you guys think about this assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceeding as normal meant that you were not considering the interior as a fluid. It might as well have been a solid.

If the fluid is non viscous, then there are no shear stresses in it due to the motion of the sphere, thus nothing to change its initial state of rest when the sphere starts rolling and no way for the fluid to affect the rolling.

So you are correct that you don't need to consider the fluid in analyzing the rolling.

Comment: Well thanks for the answer :). I am currently new here so i can't upvote but i will accept you reply as an answer <3

Answer (score 0):

If it may be true that the fluid behaves like a solid (I still have my slight doubts, which I am not able to concretize at the moment), the question remains whether this solid rotates or only translates. For the kinetic energy this makes a difference.